# How do I properly build a .NET 7 application using SkiaSharp on Linux? Getting a segmentation fault when creating GRGlInterface

Tags: .net, opengl, f#, skiasharp, skia

I have a test application written in F# on .NET 7 that opens a window using GLFW and draws to it using [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp). This application works on Windows, and now I am testing support on Linux. Right now, I am testing on a fresh install of Linux Mint, but the same exit code described here also happens on Ubuntu through WSL2.

However, my application crashes, and the only response is an exit code of 139, which apparently means there's a segmentation fault. I whittled my test application down to just GLFW, and I am able to open up a window without error. As soon as I add back in any interaction with SkiaSharp, the crash happens. I have specifically determined this to happen at the line:

```
let grGlInterface = GRGlInterface.Create(getProcAddress)
```

If I print out the string passed to `getProcAddress`, it prints out the following before the crash:

```
Name passed into `getProcAddress`: glGetString
Name passed into `getProcAddress`: glGetString
Name passed into `getProcAddress`: glGetStringi
Name passed into `getProcAddress`: glGetIntegerv
Name passed into `getProcAddress`: eglQueryString
Name passed into `getProcAddress`: eglGetCurrentDisplay
```

However, this works on both Windows and macOS.

So something is either wrong with SkiaSharp on Linux or with my dependencies.

My project file (`WindowTest.fsproj`):

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp" Version="2.88.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux" Version="2.88.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\GLFW\GLFW.fsproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="FSharp.Core" Version="6.0.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I cannot find much information about how [`SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux) is supposed to work or be used. There's also [`SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies/), which I'm not sure what it is. I guess it comes with a pre-built version of SkiaSharp or something?

My test application (`Program.fs`):

```ml
open SkiaSharp

open Windowing.GLFW.FSharp
open Windowing.GLFW.Native.Window
open Windowing.GLFW.Native.Initialization
open Windowing.GLFW.Native.Context
open Windowing.GLFW.Native.Helpers
open Windowing.GLFW.Native.OpenGL

let mutable width, height = 500, 500
let mutable framebufferWidth, framebufferHeight = width, height

let init = initialize() |> printfn "Initialized?: %A"

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4)
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6)
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE)
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)

printfn "Starting to create window..."
let window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Test Window", NULL_MONITOR, NULL_WINDOW)
printfn "Window: %A" window
printfn "Ending creating window..."

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)

let grGlInterface = GRGlInterface.Create(getProcAddress)

if not (grGlInterface.Validate())
then raise (System.Exception("Invalid GRGlInterface"))

let grContext = GRContext.CreateGl(grGlInterface)
grContext.ResetContext()

let grGlFramebufferInfo = new GRGlFramebufferInfo(0u, uint32(GL_RGBA8))


let draw(window, width, height) =
   glfwPollEvents()
   
   use grBackendRenderTarget = new GRBackendRenderTarget(width, height, 1, 0, grGlFramebufferInfo)
   use surface = SKSurface.Create(grContext, grBackendRenderTarget, GRSurfaceOrigin.BottomLeft, SKColorType.Rgba8888)
   let canvas = surface.Canvas

   canvas.Clear(SKColors.Cyan)
   canvas.Flush()

   glfwSwapBuffers(window)

let resizeCallback (window, newWidth: int, newHeight: int) =
   width <- newWidth
   height <- newHeight
   draw(window, newWidth, newHeight)

glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, GLFWframebuffersizefun(fun window width height -> resizeCallback(window, width, height)))
|> ignore

while glfwWindowShouldClose window <> 1 do
   glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &framebufferWidth, &framebufferHeight)
   draw(window, framebufferWidth, framebufferHeight)
    
glfwDestroyWindow(window)
terminate()
```

I run this application with `dotnet run --project WindowTest`. Other than the exit code of 139 that gets returned, nothing gets printed to the console except for my debug print statements. I'm not sure how to debug this further. I'm hoping there is just something I'm supposed to do more with the SkiaSharp native dependencies on Linux. These are not required on Windows. The other option is that there is a bug in SkiaSharp on Linux.

Running the command `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"` returns:

```bash
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.0.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.0.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: It has been a while. Did you solve this? I do have a segfault with Eto.Forms and SkiaSharp and was wondering if it is the same issue.

Comment: HI there. No, I did not. :( I asked on the SkiaSharp repo in both an issue and question but didn't receive a response. I am now debating about writing my own SkiaSharp bindings, specifically for desktop only, or moving to WebGPU, specifically bindings for Rust's `wgpu-native`.